# How to change the fore color of pure css animation?

Tags: css

In the following pure CSS loading, the fore color is white so it doesn't show anything on the white screen. How to change the fore-color?

```css
.lds-hourglass {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: black;
}

.lds-hourglass:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 32px solid #fff;
  border-color: #fff transparent #fff transparent;
  animation: lds-hourglass 1.2s infinite;
}

@keyframes lds-hourglass {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(900deg);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1800deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="lds-hourglass">Loading....</div>
```

Comment: Could you please put the `HTML` here ?

Comment: *fore-color* is just `color:` in CSS

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh, I tried to put the color: in the classes but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Just need to set background-color to `:before`.

see Snippet:

```css
.lds-hourglass {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;

}

    .lds-hourglass:after {
        content: " ";
        background-color:black;
        display: block;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        margin: 8px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 32px solid #fff;
        border-color: #fff transparent #fff transparent;
        animation: lds-hourglass 1.2s infinite;
    }

@keyframes lds-hourglass {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0);
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
    }

    50% {
        transform: rotate(900deg);
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(1800deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="lds-hourglass">
Loading....
</div>
```

Comment: The other two answers change the `border-color` of `.lds-hourglass:after`. Is there any difference comparing with changing the `background-color` in your answer?

Comment: @ca9163d9 no. i think you want your `border` :)

Answer (score 1):

This animation uses `borders` to generate this shape, change these values to change color :

1. border: 32px solid `#f00`;
2. border-color: `#f00` transparent `#f00` transparent;

and to change the text `loading..` color, just add this line `color: #fff` to your `lds-hourglass` style.

```css
.lds-hourglass {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #f00;
}

    .lds-hourglass:after {
        content: " ";
        display: block;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        margin: 8px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 32px solid #f00;
        border-color: #f00 transparent #f00 transparent;
        animation: lds-hourglass 1.2s infinite;
    }

@keyframes lds-hourglass {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0);
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
    }

    50% {
        transform: rotate(900deg);
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(1800deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="lds-hourglass">Loading....</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `border-color: #fff transparent #fff transparent;` with `border-color: #fff black #fff black;`

```css
.lds-hourglass {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: white;
}

    .lds-hourglass:after {
        content: " ";
        display: block;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        margin: 8px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 32px solid #fff;
        border-color: #fff black #fff black;
        animation: lds-hourglass 1.2s infinite;
    }

@keyframes lds-hourglass {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0);
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
    }

    50% {
        transform: rotate(900deg);
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(1800deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="lds-hourglass">Loading....</div>
```